# Procedure to check stability of a metric against perturbation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stability

What are broadly the procedures one needs to undertake to check the stability of a metric against small perturbations? Any review in this regard will also be helpful.

Comment: See chapters 4 and 5 from "The mathematical theory of black holes" by S.Chandrasekhar